# Scenario where it is better to use union instread of struct

Tags: c++, struct, unions

Can some give me some scenario where it is wise to use union instead of struct in some problem?

Thanks

Comment: in a trainwreck, comes to mind

Comment: What is the difference between them from your pont of view?

Comment: There is no good use for a union in C++; union is a relic of C that is entirely ignorable in the presence of [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/).

Comment: In normal application development, I would say never*. On the other hand when you have 8 MHz and 1024 bytes of memory...    *never in this case is not never-ever, such rules are not to be, but rather an indication that you should decide yourself if it is appropriate or not.

Comment: Anyone ever joined a trade struct?

Answer (score 4):

It is wise to use a union whenever you have a data bottleneck, and you have two pieces of data that are mutually exclusive, but available in the same data structure.

Let's say I have two messages that have identical data, except for two pieces of data are mutually exclusive between them, and are close in size (an 32 bit int, and a 4 byte array). I can make a union of the two, and the messages can share data structure without having an increase in size that they won't use.

Be aware of problems:

The data may not be mutually exclusive in the future.
Initialization of the mutually exclusive data.
Reusing the same instance of the data for both messages (you'll need to be sure you switch out the mutually exclusive data, or the receiver deals with junk data).

Having a union to refer to the same data with different type definitions is undefined behavior. So:

- Do not use a union to cheat the type system.
- Do not use a union to store a pointer and access an reference.
- Do not use a union to create cheaper type casting.

Also, Do not use a union with data that is a pointer which can be deleted from another point in the code. You likely have a deleted pointer in your union and accidentally refer to the data using the other definition.

*And most importantly, if you do not understand this answer. **Do not use a union.***

Comment: If you mention the undefined behaviours involved, I might +1 this good answer

Comment: If we have identical data and that data is mutually exclusive then why don't we use only a single variable for that whats the need to use two variables for them in a union...At-least if we are programming by our self then we know that when the data should be mutually exclusive?

Comment: @AbdulSamad Part of the data would be shared. You'll union only if the type definition changes between the mutually exclusive parts, necessitating two variables. If the type definition is the same, you won't need a union. Again, this is to save space only.

Comment: +1 for "Only when you know what you are doing"!!! I'd like to give another +1 for the rest of the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Unions can be a way to get at the actual binary representation of a data structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

union MyUnion {
    int integer;
    unsigned char bytes[sizeof(int)];
};

int main() {
    MyUnion foo;
    foo.integer = 42;
    std::cout << "My computer represents " << foo.integer << " as:";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(foo.bytes); ++i) {
      std::cout << ' ' << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
                << static_cast<unsigned int>(foo.bytes[i]);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There are other ways to accomplish this in C++, but using a union makes the intent rather transparent.

Note that the results may vary by platform (little-endian vs. big-endian) and possibly by compiler (how it packs and pads arrays and data types).  Most of the time, you shouldn't need to do stuff like this.

Sometimes you have to deal with a legacy binary format with several different interpretations.  ("If the first byte is a 3, then the next value is a zero-terminated ASCII string of at most 16 bytes, otherwise, the next DWORD-aligned int is an offset in the resource block ...").  If you understand all the endianness and packing issues involved, a union makes it relatively easy to tease apart such a struct.